# Less color and detail visible when videos are played in VLC (Linux, NVIDIA)

Tags: codec, linux, color, playback, vlc

When I watch videos from my GoPro, the colors look much better in Dragonplayer (stock player with KDE).  This is the case for both x264 videos:
[image: h264 encoding. Note that the detail visible in the darker parts of the image in Dragonplayer]

With HEVC there is also a difference, although I think it is less clear which one I prefer (Dragonplayer seems to have brighter colors though):

[image]

I am on Linux, but I see similar issues mentioned on Windows (related to NVIDIA cards), such as in this video:

Unfortunately the NVIDA control panel in Linux does not seem to have this "Adjust video color settings" section that the Windows one has.

I tried changing the hardware decoder in Preferences > Input/Codecs, but nothing changed whether I have it set to automatic, VA-API, VA-API w DRM, VDPAU, and disabled.

VLC was built with the following USE flags:

```
+X +a52 +alsa +aom +archive +aribsub -bidi -bluray -cddb -chromaprint -chromecast +cpu_flags_x86_mmx +cpu_flags_x86_sse +dav1d +dbus -dc1394 -debug +dts +dvbpsi +dvd +encode -faad +fdk +ffmpeg +flac -fluidsynth +fontconfig +gcrypt +gme -gnome-keyring +gstreamer +gui -ieee1394 +jack +jpeg +kate +libass -libcaca +libnotify +libsamplerate +libtar +libtiger -linsys -lirc +live +lua +lua_single_target_lua5-1 -macosx-notifications +mad +matroska -modplug +mp3 +mpeg +mtp +musepack +ncurses +nfs +ogg -omxil -optimisememory +opus +png +projectm +pulseaudio -rdp -run-as-root +samba -sdl-image -sftp -shout -sid +skins -soxr +speex +srt +ssl +svg +taglib -test -theora -tremor +truetype +twolame +udev -upnp +v4l +vaapi +vdpau -vnc +vpx +wayland +x264 +x265 +xml -zeroconf -zvbi
```

Dragon was built with just:

```
-debug
+handbook
```

My questions are two:

1. What else might I try to get VLC color looking like Dragon?
2. How might I re-encode these videos such that I can be reasonably sure that most people will see them the way I do (in Dragon)?

Edit: I found the dynamic range settings in the Linux version of NVIDIA settings, but they were already set to full, so I guess that wasn't the problem. For anyone trying to find them though, they are here:
[image]